# SQL statements locking recurrently

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, transactionscope, sqltransaction

Hello I am facing a critical issue since 2 weeks, where all the tables involved in below trigger are getting locked in a some scenario and not loading the view pages in the web application in the production region. Below SQL statement is hit continuously in the same request_session_id and when lock occurs while clients are using the application then all the tables in the trigger are getting locked and the system then works after restart of the database and IIS service. Not understanding the cause of the issue.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[tr_UpdateWorkFlowStatus]
ON [dbo].[Wf_WorkflowTaskInstanceDocuments]
FOR INSERT, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
print ''
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
     DELETE FROM triggertest
    DECLARE @Action as char(1);
    SET @Action = (CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT * FROM INSERTED)
                         AND EXISTS(SELECT * FROM DELETED)
                        THEN 'U'  -- Set Action to Updated.
                        WHEN EXISTS(SELECT * FROM INSERTED)
                        THEN 'I'  -- Set Action to Insert.
                        WHEN EXISTS(SELECT * FROM DELETED)
                        THEN 'D'  -- Set Action to Deleted.
                        ELSE NULL -- Skip. It may have been a "failed delete".   
                    END)


    DECLARE @WorkFlowNo BIGINT =(select top 1 WrokflowInstanceId from Wf_WorkflowTaskInstance WITH (NOLOCK) join inserted on inserted.WorkflowTaskInstanceId= Wf_WorkflowTaskInstance.WorkflowTaskInstanceId)
    IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Wf_WorkflowTaskInstanceDocuments WITH (NOLOCK)
                            WHERE WorkflowTaskInstanceId IN
                            (
                                    select WorkflowTaskInstanceId 
                                    from Wf_WorkflowTaskInstance 
                                    WHERE WrokflowInstanceId=@WorkFlowNo and Status<>4
                            ) 
                            AND 
                            (IsSubmitted = 0 OR IsSubmitted IS NULL)
                 ) 
    BEGIN
         UPDATE Wf_WorkflowInstance SET Status='Completed' where WorkflowInstanceId=@WorkFlowNo
    END
    ELSE IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Wf_WorkflowTaskInstanceDocuments WITH (NOLOCK)
                            WHERE WorkflowTaskInstanceId IN
                            (
                                    select WorkflowTaskInstanceId 
                                    from Wf_WorkflowTaskInstance 
                                    WHERE WrokflowInstanceId=@WorkFlowNo
                            ) 
                            AND 
                            (IsSubmitted = 1)
                 ) 
    BEGIN
        UPDATE Wf_WorkflowInstance SET Status='InProgress' where WorkflowInstanceId=@WorkFlowNo
    END
    if exists(select 1  from Wf_WorkflowTaskInstanceDocuments WITH (NOLOCK) where participants is null)
        update Wf_WorkflowTaskInstanceDocuments set participants=dbo.[GetTaskDocumentAssignees](WorkflowTaskInstanceDocumentsId)  where participants is null 

    if(@Action='u')
    begin
        if exists(select 1 from Wf_WorkflowTaskInstanceDocuments WITH (NOLOCK) where len(ToParticipants)<>len(dbo.UDF_DistinctList(ToParticipants,',')) and WorkflowTaskInstanceDocumentsId in(select WorkflowTaskInstanceDocumentsId from inserted))
        begin
            update Wf_WorkflowTaskInstanceDocuments set ToParticipants=dbo.UDF_DistinctList(ToParticipants,','),participants=dbo.[GetTaskDocumentAssignees](WorkflowTaskInstanceDocumentsId) 
            where WorkflowTaskInstanceDocumentsId in(select WorkflowTaskInstanceDocumentsId from inserted)
        end
        else
            update Wf_WorkflowTaskInstanceDocuments set participants=dbo.[GetTaskDocumentAssignees](WorkflowTaskInstanceDocumentsId)  where WorkflowTaskInstanceDocumentsId in(select WorkflowTaskInstanceDocumentsId from inserted)
    end

     if(@Action='I')
     BEGIN  
                     insert into Wf_WorkflowTaskDocumentVersionMapping
                     (
                         WorkflowTaskInstanceId,
                         Wf_WorkflowInstanceDocID,
                         DocRegisterID
                     )
                     select  
                     WorkflowTaskInstanceId,
                     WorkflowTaskInstanceDocumentsId,
                     DocumentRegisterID
                     from 
                     Wf_WorkflowTaskInstanceDocuments WHERE WorkflowTaskInstanceDocumentsId not IN(SELECT Wf_WorkflowInstanceDocID FROM Wf_WorkflowTaskDocumentVersionMapping WITH (NOLOCK))

                   DECLARE @DOCID AS TABLE
                            (
                              DocumentRegisterID INT,
                              WorkflowTaskInstanceDocumentsId INT,
                              WorkflowTaskInstanceId INT
                            )
                            DECLARE @WorkflowTaskInstanceId INT
                            DECLARE @WorkflowInstanceId INT=0
                            DECLARE @CurrentWorkflowInstanceId INT=0
                            DECLARE @DocumentRegisterID INT=0
                            DECLARE @WorkflowTaskInstanceDocumentsId INT=0
                            DECLARE @Wf_WorkflowTaskDocumentVersionMapping INT=0
                            DECLARE @Wf_TaskInstanceLocal INT=0
                            DECLARE @RowCount int=0
                            DECLARE @DocVersionLocal int
                            DECLARE @RevisionLocal varchar(25)
                            DECLARE @FirstTaskInstanceID int=(select top 1 wti.WorkflowTaskInstanceId from Wf_WorkflowTaskDocumentVersionMapping wtid
                                                 join Wf_WorkflowTaskInstance  wti WITH (NOLOCK) on wtid.WorkflowTaskInstanceId=wti.WorkflowTaskInstanceId
                                                 where wti.WrokflowInstanceId IN(@WorkFlowNo) order by wti.WorkflowTaskInstanceId)
                            DELETE FROM @DOCID
                            INSERT INTO @DOCID SELECT DocumentRegisterID,WorkflowTaskInstanceDocumentsId,WorkflowTaskInstanceId FROM Wf_WorkflowTaskInstanceDocuments WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE WorkflowTaskInstanceId=@FirstTaskInstanceID 


                            DECLARE @AdsdDocVersionMappingParent CURSOR
                            SET @AdsdDocVersionMappingParent = CURSOR FAST_FORWARD
                            FOR
                                select DocumentRegisterID
                                ,WorkflowTaskInstanceId 
                                from @DOCID
                            OPEN @AdsdDocVersionMappingParent
                            FETCH NEXT FROM @AdsdDocVersionMappingParent
                            INTO @DocumentRegisterID
                            ,@WorkflowTaskInstanceId
                            WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
                            BEGIN
                            set @DocVersionLocal=(select top 1 DocVersion from DocumentRegisterLogs where source like '%auto superseded by workflow%' and DocumentRegisterID=@DocumentRegisterID order by DocumentRegisterLogsID desc)
                            set @RevisionLocal=(select top 1 Revision from DocumentRegisterLogs where source like '%auto superseded by workflow%' and DocumentRegisterID=@DocumentRegisterID order by DocumentRegisterLogsID desc)
                                                    DECLARE @AdsdDocVersionMapping CURSOR
                                                    SET @AdsdDocVersionMapping = CURSOR FAST_FORWARD
                                                    FOR
                                                    select wti.WorkflowTaskInstanceId,wtid.Wf_WorkflowInstanceDocID 
                                                    from Wf_WorkflowTaskDocumentVersionMapping wtid WITH (NOLOCK)
                                                    join Wf_WorkflowTaskInstance wti WITH (NOLOCK) on wtid.WorkflowTaskInstanceId=wti.WorkflowTaskInstanceId
                                                    where wti.WrokflowInstanceId IN(@WorkFlowNo) and wtid.DocRegisterID is null
                                                    OPEN @AdsdDocVersionMapping
                                                    FETCH NEXT FROM @AdsdDocVersionMapping
                                                    INTO @WorkflowTaskInstanceId,@WorkflowTaskInstanceDocumentsId
                                                    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
                                                    BEGIN
                                                                if not exists(select 1 from Wf_WorkflowTaskDocumentVersionMapping where DocRegisterID=@DocumentRegisterID and WorkflowTaskInstanceId=@WorkflowTaskInstanceId and DocRegisterID is not null)
                                                                begin
                                                                         update Wf_WorkflowTaskDocumentVersionMapping set DocRegisterID=@DocumentRegisterID where Wf_WorkflowInstanceDocID=@WorkflowTaskInstanceDocumentsId 
                                                                         update Wf_WorkflowTaskDocumentVersionMapping set DocVersion=@DocVersionLocal,Revision=@RevisionLocal where Wf_WorkflowInstanceDocID=@WorkflowTaskInstanceDocumentsId  
                                                                         select @WorkflowTaskInstanceDocumentsId
                                                                end
                                                                        --//////=
                                                                            update a set a.DocVersion=b.DocVersion
                                                                            from Wf_WorkflowTaskDocumentVersionMapping a
                                                                            join DocumentRegisterLogs b on a.DocRegisterID=b.DocumentRegisterID
                                                                            join Wf_WorkflowTaskInstance wti on wti.WorkflowTaskInstanceId=a.WorkflowTaskInstanceId
                                                                            where b.Source like '%auto superseded by workflow%' and (a.DocVersion is null)
                                                                            and wti.WrokflowInstanceId=@WorkFlowNo
                                                                            and wti.WorkflowTaskInstanceId=@WorkflowTaskInstanceId

                                                                            update a set a.Revision=b.Revision
                                                                            from Wf_WorkflowTaskDocumentVersionMapping a
                                                                            join DocumentRegisterLogs b on a.DocRegisterID=b.DocumentRegisterID
                                                                            join Wf_WorkflowTaskInstance wti on wti.WorkflowTaskInstanceId=a.WorkflowTaskInstanceId
                                                                            where b.Source like '%auto superseded by workflow%' and (a.Revision is null)
                                                                            and wti.WrokflowInstanceId=@WorkFlowNo
                                                                            and wti.WorkflowTaskInstanceId=@WorkflowTaskInstanceId
                                                                        --//////

                                                    FETCH NEXT FROM @AdsdDocVersionMapping
                                                    INTO @WorkflowTaskInstanceId,@WorkflowTaskInstanceDocumentsId
                                                    END
                                                    CLOSE @AdsdDocVersionMapping
                                                    DEALLOCATE @AdsdDocVersionMapping
                            FETCH NEXT FROM @AdsdDocVersionMappingParent
                            INTO @DocumentRegisterID
                            ,@WorkflowTaskInstanceId
                            END
                            CLOSE @AdsdDocVersionMappingParent
                            DEALLOCATE @AdsdDocVersionMappingParent
                update a set a.DocVersion=b.DocVersion
                from Wf_WorkflowTaskDocumentVersionMapping a
                join DocumentRegisterLogs b on a.DocRegisterID=b.DocumentRegisterID
                join Wf_WorkflowTaskInstance wti on wti.WorkflowTaskInstanceId=a.WorkflowTaskInstanceId
                where b.Source like '%auto superseded by workflow%' and (a.DocVersion is null)
                and wti.WrokflowInstanceId=@WorkFlowNo


                update a set a.Revision=b.Revision
                from Wf_WorkflowTaskDocumentVersionMapping a
                join DocumentRegisterLogs b on a.DocRegisterID=b.DocumentRegisterID
                join Wf_WorkflowTaskInstance wti on wti.WorkflowTaskInstanceId=a.WorkflowTaskInstanceId
                where b.Source like '%auto superseded by workflow%' and (a.Revision is null)
                and wti.WrokflowInstanceId=@WorkFlowNo
                and b.DocumentRegisterLogsID in(select top 1000 DocumentRegisterLogsID from DocumentRegisterLogs where DocumentRegisterID=b.DocumentRegisterID order by DocumentRegisterLogsID desc)
     END
       if(@Action='u')
       BEGIN
               DECLARE @DocumentNoInst varchar(120)
               DECLARE @DocumentNoVer varchar(120)
               DECLARE @DocumentIDVer int
               DECLARE @DocumentVer int
               DECLARE @DocInID int
               SELECT @DocumentNoInst=dr.DocumentNo,@DocInID=WorkflowTaskInstanceDocumentsId FROM inserted ins JOIN DocumentRegister dr on ins.DocumentRegisterID=dr.DocumentRegisterID
               SELECT @DocumentNoVer=dr.DocumentNo FROM Wf_WorkflowTaskDocumentVersionMapping insver JOIN DocumentRegister dr WITH (NOLOCK) on insver.DocRegisterID=dr.DocumentRegisterID  where Wf_WorkflowInstanceDocID=@DocInID 
               if(@DocumentNoInst<>@DocumentNoVer)
               begin
                       select top 1 @DocumentIDVer=DocRegisterID,@DocumentVer=insver.DocVersion from Wf_WorkflowTaskDocumentVersionMapping insver JOIN DocumentRegister dr on insver.DocRegisterID=dr.DocumentRegisterID
                                              where WorkflowTaskInstanceId in(@FirstTaskInstanceID) and dr.DocumentNo=@DocumentNoInst
                        update Wf_WorkflowTaskDocumentVersionMapping set DocRegisterID=@DocumentIDVer,DocVersion=@DocumentVer where Wf_WorkflowInstanceDocID=@DocInID
               end

       END
         -----------------------------------------***********************************-------------------------------------------
     Declare @AllTasksCount int=(select count(1) from Wf_WorkflowTaskInstance WITH (NOLOCK) where WrokflowInstanceId=@WorkFlowNo)
     declare @SkippedTasksCount int=(select count(1) from Wf_WorkflowTaskInstance WITH (NOLOCK) where WrokflowInstanceId=@WorkFlowNo and Status=4)
     if(@AllTasksCount=@SkippedTasksCount)
     begin
        update Wf_WorkflowInstance set Status='Skipped' where WorkflowInstanceId=@WorkFlowNo
     end
END
```

Comment: `DELETE FROM triggertest`? A typo'ed column`WrokflowInstanceId`? A trigger that doesn't properly handle statements that affect more than one row? Nested loops with cursors? A `SELECT TOP(1000)` seemingly apropos of nothing? [`NOLOCK` sprinkled everywhere](https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/)? My advice is to scrap this and start over with stored procedures to encapsulte the logic of actions on workflows. If that's not an option and you're just tasked with "fixing it somehow", I wish you the best of luck. It's not something I'd look into for free.

Comment: It is very confusing to use both 2012 and 2008 sql-server tag.

Comment: @VojtěchDohnal edited

Comment: This trigger can probably be showcased in a study on *how/when not to use triggers*, and *what not to do inside a trigger*. I'm sorry that this is not a very constructive comment, all it is saying is that you are doing it wrong. You should analyze what the trigger does and why, and come up with a solution that *doesn't* do this all from within a trigger.

Comment: @TT. thank for the comment. This trigger was in use since years in this application written by some ex employee. I will analyse it and try to remove the trigger it self and handle the same via application or SP

Comment: @user7721524 Yes, we've all been in that situation, sadly. Another thing to try and get rid of, is the double cursor loop. I didn't try to understand what it does, but typically it is better to work with set-based constructs rather than looping using cursor. I wish you good luck!

Comment: This problem is hardly solvable here, you would have to narrow it first.